# Clone-on-drag with aurealia-interactjs

Tags: aurelia, interact.js

I'm trying to use interactjs with aurelia to have a system where dragging clones the dragged object, rather than moves it.

According to the interactjs FAQ (http://interactjs.io/docs/faq/#clone-target-draggable), this can be done using the move pointer event in interactjs. However, aurelia-interactjs doesn't appear to expose the interactjs pointer events.

Is there another way to accomplish this, beyond the method described in the interactjs FAQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to answer my own question. There's an alternative method of creating the clone, outlined by Magnum79 here: https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/156

Using that instead of the interact move() one obviates the need to have pointer events supported in aurelia-interactjs. A slight modification for positioning, and translation into aurelia yields:

```
dragStart(event) {
    event = event.detail;
    if (!event.target.dragOrigin) {
        var clone = event.target.cloneNode(true);
        clone.dragOrigin = event.target;
        event.interaction.element = clone;
        event.interaction.dragging = false;
        var dragTarget = clone;
        document.body.appendChild(clone);
        var r = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        clone.style.position = 'absolute';
        clone.style.left = r.left + 'px';
        clone.style.top = r.top + 'px';
    } else {
        dragTarget = event.target;
    }
}
```

Which works like a charm.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make your code above like a toolbar drag and drop? lets say it's a input box i want to drag that over then have the ability to drag another input box. right now once the drag and drop is complete the object is not able to drag again

Comment: @AndreDeMattia: This is a new question. I suggest you make a new question linking to this one :)